# Google Maps API vector map falling back to raster

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been building a website which includes a Google vector map. Up until today the vector map was functioning correctly, but now it has begun failing to load as a vector and falling back to raster. The fallback occurs in Chrome and Brave, but the vector map still loads in Safari. I have confirmed that the GPU settings in Chrome are correct. I have tried creating a new mapId. I have confirmed that all browsers have WebGL 2 support with the following code:

```
        // check for WebGL support
        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.getContext("webgl2") ? console.log("WebGL 2 is supported") : console.log("WebGL 2 is NOT supported");

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: 41.798057, lng: -93.973488},
            zoom: 3,
            mapTypeId: 'satellite',
            streetViewControl: false,
            mapId: "xxxxxx",
        });

        map.addListener("renderingtype_changed", () => {
            console.log(map.getRenderingType());
        });
```

Is there any other way that I might be able to figure out exactly what might be causing the fallback in Chrome and Brave? Just to reiterate, I didn't make any changes to the code when the vector map stopped loading, so I'm wondering if some setting within Google changed that I'm not aware of?

UPDATE: I updated my browser and the issue resolved itself. I have submitted a bug report to Google's issue tracker.

Comment: Hello, can you provide the link of the bug?

Comment: they have it marked as fixed. I haven't experienced the issue recently but I'm still not sure if the problem was browser related or an issue with the map api.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/294002979